# Using sed to Download ComboFix automatically

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

I'm trying to write a shell script to grab the dynamic URL which ComboFix is located at at [BleepingComputer.com/download/combofix](http://BleepingComputer.com/download/combofix)

However, for some reason I can't seem to get my regex to match the download link of the "click here" if the download doesn't work. I used a regex tester and it said I matched the link, but I can't seem to get it to work when I execute it, it turns up an empty result. Here's my entire script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # Download latest ComboFix from BleepingComputer
 wget -O Listing.html "http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/" -nv
 downloadpage=$(sed -ne 's@^.*<a href="\(http://www[.]bleepingcomputer[.]com/download/combofix/dl/[0-9]\+/\)" class="goodurl">.*$@\1@p' Listing.html)
 echo "DL Page: $downloadpage"
 secondpage="$downloadpage"
 wget -O Download.html $secondpage -nv
 file=$(sed -ne 's@^.*<a href="\(http://download[.]bleepingcomputer[.]com/dl/[0-9A-Fa-f]\+/[0-9A-Fa-f]\+/windows/security/anti[-]virus/c/combofix/ComboFix[.]exe\)">.*$@\1@p' Download.html)
 echo "File: $file"
 wget -O "ComboFix.exe" "$file" -nv
 rm Listing.html
 rm Download.html
 mkdir Tools
 mv "ComboFix.exe" "Tools/ComboFix.exe" -f
```

The first two downloads work successfully, and I end up with:
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/dl/12/

But it fails to match the final sed that will give me the download link.

The code it's supposed to match is:

```
<a href="http://download.bleepingcomputer.com/dl/6c497ccbaff8226ec84c97dcdfc3ce9a/5058d931/windows/security/anti-virus/c/combofix/ComboFix.exe">click here</a>
```

SOLUTION:

For anyone interested, the final code that worked was:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Download latest ComboFix from BleepingComputer
wget -O Download.html "http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/12" -nv
file=$(sed -ne 's@^.*<a href=\x27\(http://download[.]bleepingcomputer[.]com/dl/[0-9A-Fa-f]\+/[0-9A-Fa-f]\+/windows/security/anti[-]virus/c/combofix/ComboFix[.]exe\)\x27>.*$@\1@p' Download.html)
echo "File URL: $file"
wget -OSN "ComboFix.exe" "$file" -nv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's funny: I just went to http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/dl/12/ and found

> <a href='http://download.bleepingcomputer.com/dl/587c6038..../..../ComboFix.exe'>click here</a>.

i.e., the URL is delimited by single quotes (**'**) rather than double quotes (**"**) (which is what your `sed` command is looking for).

Comment: How very strange, I'm viewing it in Chrome and I'm seeing double quotes

Comment: You're right though, that's the problem, I viewed the Download.html file and it has single quotes

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to download the first page as the second page is static.  It will always be:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/dl/12/

It is also strongly suggested that you use the **-N** flag on wget to check timestamps. This will only download ComboFix if its newer then the one on your computer.

Also make sure your script only runs once or twice a day.  There is no need to run it more than that.

By limiting the requests and using the -N, you should avoid being automatically banned by our scripts.

Thanks

Comment: I wasn't certain if the first one was static or not, since otherwise the number seems unnecessary, thanks for letting me know.

Currently the script only runs once a day at night, I'll be sure to add the -N to it, thanks for the tip and inside information :)